# Time reversal of odd signals

Tags: signal-processing, reflection

This question is about the “reflect about the $y$ axis” method of finding $x(-t)$ for a given $x(t)$. How does this method work if the signal is odd to begin with? Let’s say it is a signal whose equation is not obvious ,as the one shown in figure:

[image]

**Let’s say that we have were only shown the shape in the positive $x$ axis**, how do I know that I have to take $-x(t)$ for the reflected version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[reflection of an odd function about y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQPiz.png)

So I added an **image** which shows the reflected version($x(-t)$), of $x(t)$ about the $y$ axis.

Suppose you have a domain of definition $\Delta = (a,b)$ for the function $x(t)$. To find $x(-t)$ you must consider $-t \in (a,b)$. So it follows that $t \in (-b,-a)$. If you choose a random value for $t,$ let it be $u_0 = -t_0 \in (-b,-a)$ then  $$x(-u_o) = x(t_0)$$ and $$t_0 \in \Delta  = (a,b)$$ Thus the point $(-t_o, x(t_0))$ of the function $z(t) = x(-t)$ is the symmetric about the $y$-axis of the point $(t_0, x(t_0))$, which belongs to the original signal x(t).

Following this method for every point of $x(t)$, what you manage to accomplish is to reflect the function about the y-axis.

You understand of course all the above I suppose. Until now I have not mentioned anything about the oddness of the signal. It does not make a difference for the method of reflection about the $y$-axis.

**However**, as you can see, the result of finding $x(-t)$ leads a to the same signal as if we were to take  $$x(-t) = - x(t)$$ i.e. the symmetric of the signal about the $x$-axis.

**Note:** in the photo I have written $t_0$ as $x_0$ and $x(t_0)$ as $f(x_0)$. Sorry for the inconsistency(from habit).